# Quickest way to access a webservice with WSDL in Java

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I need to access a webservice from Java. [The service has a WSDL](http://vas.mikro-odeme.com/services/msaleservice.asmx?wsdl). Now how do I get to calling its operations?

- I've already used `wsimport` on it, but that only generates XML objects for the operations/responses, nothing to actually call them.
- I've looked at [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference) but it doesn't look like it's completely what I want (even though it might be part of the solution). The word "wsdl" doesn't appear in that page at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wsimport` does not only generate the Objects needed for communication with the service but also a service client. Create an instance of the class `MSaleService` and fetch the port with `getMSaleServiceSoap()`. That's it.

There *might* be some problems though. `wsimport` complained about

> [WARNING] SOAP port "MSaleServiceSoap12": uses a non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
>   line 530 of http://vas.mikro-odeme.com/services/msaleservice.asmx?wsdl

but I don't know if this poses real problems.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked those objects. So that's all I need? That's pretty easy then. The warning shouldn't cause trouble, since it's only an alternative port.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick link I found

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC5.html

Basically, this type of calling is calling Dynamic Invocation where you would **NOT** need to know the WSDL apriori.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, there's this *wizard* that let's you create what's called a new "Web Service Client" just by pointing at your wsdl file.

so if you have your wsdl in your project, then just click on "new" and choose the wizard.

it'll ask you for the wsdl file and some other info (you can choose your runtime -Axis, Axis2, CXF...).

i think this wizard is part of WTP (www.eclipse.org/webtools).

take a look:

http://tinyurl.com/5v56s5u

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/WebServiceClient/WebServiceClient.html