# SOAP port uses a non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding

Tags: soap, webservice-client, wsimport, jaxws-maven-plugin, soap1.2

I am using the [jaxws maven plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) to generate webservices access classes. During the generation the following warning is printed:

[WARNING] SOAP port "MyServicePort" uses a non-standard SOAP 1.2 binding.
line XXX of http://...?wsdl

By adding an additional argument (`-extension`) I got it to work however I am wondering what this error is about? SOAP 1.2 Binding seems [official](http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/soap12WSDL.htm)  to me - so whats the problem?

The namespace defition of the wsdl is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="FooServerInvoker" 

targetNamespace="http://ws.server.foo.com/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:tns="http://ws.server.jadice.levigo.com/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

The problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280907/quickest-way-to-access-a-webservice-with-wsdl-in-java) where you can find an example wsdl if you want to try out.

Comment: I add the same problem with this WSDL: https://www-qa.netdocs.com.pt/tradehttpQA/CTMessageService.svc?singleWsdl

Comment: Hello, how did you add the `-extension` argument?

Comment: @YassirKhaldi in `pom.xml` update the plugin configuration: in the `<configuration>` element add `<args>` with child element `<arg>-extension</arg>`

Comment: still have the warning after adding <arg>-extension</arg> and <extension>true</extension> for com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin:4.0.1